# DotNetNuke Install.aspx?mode=InstallResources Automation

Tags: tfs, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

**Issue:**

I am trying to automate the build and installation of `DNN` modules on a build server.  We are currently using `DNN 5.5` and `TFS` for source control and build automation. The `TFS` build works as expected (getting, compiling, building/copying DNN packages) but when executing the `Install.aspx?mode=InstallResources` URL we get the "Site is under construction". The event log for `DNN` does not reveal any information. If I log in to the build server using my Id or the build server id and run the this script, everything works as expected.  It’s when the script is started from the scheduler that the `DNN InstallResouces` URL has issues.  The build id used is an administrator on the build server.  I have search the web for others doing the same but only found one that stated they wrote an exe utility that submits a HTTP request and parses the response for the success or fail of the resources.  Is this the only option? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you nit work with Instances of your software from build. It is a bad practice and you need many workarounds to get things going. I would recommend that you install Release Management which is specifically designed to do what you are asking. It just has better tooling and configuration options for this.

- http://nakedalm.com/building-release-pipeline-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

I created a post on this not to long ago and you can get more info in Professional ALM with Visual Studio 2013 on building and configuring a release pipeline. This way you are deploying tested binaries and not creating untested new ones for future deployments.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  We already have a release management process for moving source to the test and production environments.  This specific issue was to automate the movement of developer source to a development lab server.  thanks.

Comment: Again you are moving sources not binaries. You would be better served moving to a binary promotion model...

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:  The issue was resolved by setting the correct permissions for the TFS build user to execute the DNN install resources.  The script being executed needed to load the Windows user profile when the script was being executed.